# SharedPreferences but on c# Windows Form Apps C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a simple messages program, in which u can talk to other people.

Currently, I'm working on the login screen and I want to create a "remember me" option which will save your credentials the next time u enter the app. I worked a bit with android Studio,and Unity, and they both use something called `SharedPreferences`, I used it and it's great. So I wanna know if there is a `SharedPreferences` for C# and how to use it on a Windows Form App.

Any help is accepted.

Comment: No, you will have to write your own code for this.

Comment: Be aware that you comparing frameworks with a programming language. A language don't store credentials. OS's and frameworks do or might do. To recommend something we would need to know what you are targeting. Windows desktop, WinRT/UWP, Net Core(Multiplattform) etc.

Comment: For WinForms, you can use [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In winforms, we usually use `Settings` to keep the user setting info.

To achieve the requirement, you can refer to the following steps:

1.Click "Project" and choose "Setting Properties…", then choose "Settings"
[image]

2.Add new setting in "Settings"
[image]

3.Try the following code:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the current state of the checkbox
    Properties.Settings.Default.cb = checkBoxRememberMe.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.str = textBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load checkbox state from settings
    checkBoxRememberMe.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.cb;
    textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.str;
}
```