# How to get value from App Settings in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 connection strings saved in Settings section of the app in Visual Studio.

How do I retrieve those fields in C# as I have only ever used VB and the below code:

```
My.Settings.*SettingName*
```

Seems that simple that its hard to find a clear answer for :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SharedPreferences but on c# Windows Form Apps C# Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142729/sharedpreferences-but-on-c-sharp-windows-form-apps-c-sharp-visual-studio)

Comment: What kind of project do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the Settings in `Project->Properties…->Settings`, you can access them by `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`.

For more info, you can refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65175118/8335151

Answer (score 1):

You could stored the connection string as a key in the configuration file as [shown here](http://%20%20%20%20%22svn.path%22:%20%22C:%5C%5CProgram%20Files%5C%5CTortoiseSVN%5C%5CBin%5C%5Csvn.exe%22,%20%20%20%20%20%22svn.refresh.remoteChanges%22:%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%22TortoiseSVN.tortoiseSVNProcExePath%22:%20%22C:%5C%5CProgram%20Files%5C%5CTortoiseSVN%5C%5Cbin%5C%5CTortoiseProc.exe%22,).

Add a reference for [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) then read setting. In the following it's been done for Entity Framework but can work for conventional data access via a connection and command. You could also add in the data provider in your connection strings. Other than that depending on the project type you could also store information in [appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/configuration/appsettings.json).

All code below is [here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/EntityFramework-environment-connections/blob/master/EntityFrameworkCoreLibrary/Contexts/NorthWindContext.cs).
[image: code]

Note the constants are in this case done under project properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio 2017**

*Code in Controller action (to fetch the settings)*

```
var appsettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSupport"].ToString();
var consettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMDBContext"].ToString();
```

*Web.config*

[image: Web.config]

Things are different for Visual Studio 2019, .net core